# Is this European(western), Eastern(northern) or another Hedgehog?

Tags: species-identification

Yesterday this little guy ambushed my bicycle, thankfully tire-hedgehog contact was avoided at the last moment. Now I am wondering which one is it. Going by wikipedia maps and photos it should be either [European/Western (*Erinaceus europaeus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_hedgehog) or [Northern (*E. roumanicus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_white-breasted_hedgehog).

Sadly due to nocturnal nature of Hedgehog, "smart"phone camera and general willingness of Mr. Spikey to quickly leave area of incident this is best photo I have:

[image: HEDGEHOG]

Incident occurred in Poland, Europe, around 21:30 local time.

Comment: There are some field marks that can be used to make the distinction but you should have taken a picture of the foot and the nose more precisely. There is still the risk of some variations in colour, then the best would be a DNA analysis in my opinion.

Comment: What part of Poland is this? Both species occur in Poland, but they are geographically seperated.

Comment: @RHA It was [about here, in Opole, Upper Silesia](https://www.google.pl/maps/place/50%C2%B040'16.8%22N+17%C2%B054'36.5%22E/@50.671342,17.9089996,289m/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the picture you have is not enough to make a proper distinction between the two species.

By [this site](http://wildpro.twycrosszoo.org/S/0MInsectivor/Erinaceidae/Erinaceus/Erinaceus_europaeus/20WEHSpecVar.htm), they found some morphological characteristics to make the distinction but:

1. You have to carefully take pictures of the animal parts
2. The study nearer Poland has been made in Estonia and those characteristics could be slightly different in other countries.

I did not find another documents about hedgehog populations in Poland but the wikipedia page says both species are living in the country.

Comment: Downvoters: please consider to leave a comment to explain what can be improved to this answer.